# Spring oauth2 validate token request

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, access-token

Does oauth2RestTemplate or access token providers support validate token request?

Here is the flow:

1. Mobile/Web-App authenticated from third party Authentication server
   and obtains Access-Token.
2. User tries to access a secured resources, and passed the Access-Token in the request, as expected by the protocol.

Is it possible to check this token against third-party server?

I found a bit similar [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token#)  in the form of a refresh token.

Is validation request the part of the OAuth2 standard?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, OAuth2 doesn't enforce a specific token format or API for validating tokens. This is something that has to be decided independently between the resource server and the authorization server.

For example, the [UAA](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/) project, which uses Spring Security OAuth2, uses signed [JWT](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-06) tokens, so the resource server can validate the contents without having to ask the authorization server directly. It also provides a `/check_token` endpoint, which will decode the token and verify that it has not expired.